# How can I make the text of a button change in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button in HTML:

```
<button>     </button>
```

How can I make the change inside change depending on the value of a $scope variable?

```
$scope.action == Action.Authenticating
```

I would like it to say "Sign in" when this is false and "Signing in..." when it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) inside a binding:

```
<button>{{action === "someValue" ? "Primary" : "Alternate"}}</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
<button>{{action ? 'Signing in...' : 'Sign in'}}</button>
```